# What is the most effective forum to request functionality from Apple?

Tags: ios

I have a 4s and would like to suggest wifi calling compatibility with T-mobile.

I have setup a SIP client on a iphone 4 and unaware of any technical reason UMA or similar VOIP compatibility can not be done. Given that IOS supports wifi calling on the 5: why is this not available in the 4S?

Although I have already posed two questions, I would like to know the most effective forum to pose the request to apple to enable UMA VOIP capability for the iPhone 4S.

Comment: The normal place to suggest such things is http://www.apple.com/feedback  but they will not answer you and I cannot imagine them ever spending any time on such a request given their focus on future oriented devices and iOS versions.

Answer (score 1):

iPhone 4s is five years old and no longer receives iOS updates. While I suppose stranger things have happened, the likelihood of it receiving any new functionality at this stage is so remote as to be essentially zero.